# How to use Asymptote system() command

Tags: asymptote

**Edit: I have since upgraded to release 2.37 with the same result.**

I'm running `asymptote 2.15` on `Windows 7`.  I'm trying to use the `int system(string s)` command for the first time to call a system command.  The manual says...

> If the setting safe is false, then the functions int system(string s) and int system(string[] s) can be used to call the arbitrary system command s.

I created a file `sample.asy` containing

```
int i = system("dir");
write(i);
```

and call it with

```
asy runThermalModel.asy -nosafe
```

The resulting output at the command line is

```
Cannot execute dir
255
```

I get similar output for other `DOS` commands that I have tried.  Can someone tell me how to properly use the `system()` function?

Comment: Under Linux it works. Path problem or some W7 permission ? Or launch command tool with full path.

Comment: Oddly enough, I get exactly the same error on my Mac when I try `system("dir")`. Have you tried using linux/unix commands (e.g., `system("ls")`) instead of DOS commands?

Comment: @O.G.: I assume that the command should run in the same directory containing the `asy` file and I do have permissions there.  I'm not sure what the last sentence means in the context of the `system` command.  Thank you for letting me know that it works on Linux.

Comment: @CharlesStaats: The `ls` command didn't work either (`Cannot execute ls`).  I'm using the pre-compiled binary for windows.  Do you think that perhaps there was a configuration flag disallowing system calls when the binary was created?  I don't see anything in the manual about that being a possibility though.

Comment: Hmm, works for me on Win 10 using the latest released version.

Comment: Thanks @MindV0rtex.  That's good news.  I have a new Win 10 workstation on order (for unrelated reasons).